# Yii2 - When inserting record this is duplicate automatically

Tags: php, yii2

this form receives + - 400 records daily, very rarely when making a record this is automatically duplicated with a difference of 1 or 2 seconds.

**NumsController.php**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Nums();
    $model->scenario = Nums::SCENARIO_CREATE;

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

        try {
            if ($model->treatment == 3 && ($model->cc == null || $model->cc == '')) {
                if ($EmailTo = filter_var($model->idUser->email,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL))
                Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                    ->setFrom('xxxxxx')
                    ->setTo($EmailTo)
                    ->setCc(array('xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx'))
                    ->setSubject("xxxxxx")
                    ->setTextBody('Plain Text content')
                    ->setHtmlBody(
                        "Email Text Example")
                    ->send();
            }elseif ($model->treatment == 3 && ($model->cc != null && $model->cc != '')){
                if ($EmailTo = filter_var($model->idUser->email,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL))
                if($EmailCC = filter_var($model->cc,FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL))
                Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                    ->setFrom('xxxxxx')
                    ->setTo($EmailTo)
                    ->setCc(array($EmailCC, 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx'))
                    ->setSubject("xxxxxx")
                    ->setTextBody('Plain Text content')
                    ->setHtmlBody(
                        "Other Email Text Example")
                    ->send();
            }
            return $this->redirect(['create']);

        }catch(Swift_SwiftException $exception){
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('warning', "Email not sent");
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }

    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I know the code is confusing but will it be the code problem?
Could be server problem? is that it happens a few times, in 400 it happens only 2 times.

**i have one Conditional Validator like this**

```
['id_user', 'required',
            'when' => function ($model) {
                return $model->treatment == '2' OR $model->treatment == '3';
            },
            'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
                return $('#treatment').val() == '2' || $('#treatment').val() == '3';
            }",

            'on' => self::SCENARIO_CREATE
        ],
```

Update

**beforeValidate() in common\models\Nums.php**

```
public function beforeValidate()
{
    if ($this->scenario == self::SCENARIO_CREATE){
        $this->a = Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
        $this->date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }else {
        $this->a = $this->a;
        $this->date = $this->date;
    }

    return parent::beforeValidate(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
}
```

Comment: I don't see problem in your code, but if you use AJAX for saving the form, may be an actor try to click again on the submit button before form submission.

Comment: I'm not using ajax. This is probably the strangest bug I've ever seen..

Comment: I remembered that I have an extra validation, i update my question, it may help..

Comment: I see your update, but could not be it. You must be create log from happens and results in your code. Or use delay in the save condition to test when php is waiting for send email, could be call again this action?

Comment: I tested with `sleep()` but not duplicate automatically, 
and this should not be because if the first or second `if` is `false`, save without sending the email

Comment: there may be some problem with `return $this->redirect(["create"])`after save?

Comment: No, because this happen is very rarely. If it has a problem, must be duplicate in every request.

Comment: the above does not give any clue for a duplicated record other than the call to you action for any particular records is received twice. Between the `else` part in the `beforValidate()` method does not make any sense, it wont make a difference if you remove it altogether

Comment: solved! the problem was because of the delay of the email the user clicked twice on the button submit. :/